# как сделать нормальный фон позади слова

Tags: html, css, border

```css
#faq {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
}

#faq div {
 width: 25%;
 margin-left: 6%;
 float: left;
 border: 2px solid #DEDEDE;
 border-radius: 7px;
 background-color: #DEDEDE;
 border-bottom: 90px solid #DEDEDE;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)

}

#faq div img {
 width: 94%;
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

#faq .title {
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #a3a0ad;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 2.2em;

}

#faq .heading {
 color: #7d7d7d;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#faq p {
 font-family: Arimo, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #4a4a4a;
 font-size: 0.95em;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#second {
 margin-top: 10px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 background-color: orange;
 border-left: 100px solid orange;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-right: 25%; 
 padding: 10px
}
```

```html
 <h2><div id="second">Новости о главном...</div></h2>
 <div id="faq">
  <div>
   <img src="img/7.jpg">
   <span class="title"></span><br>
   <span class="heading"></span>
   <p></p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="img/7.jpg">
   <span class="title"></span><br>
   <span class="heading"></span>
   <p></p>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="img/7.jpg">
   <span class="title"></span><br>
   <span class="heading"></span>
   <p></p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу укоротить фон. Прикрепляю два скрина на одном как у меня, а на другом, как надо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не понял что вы имеете ввиду под "нормальный фон", а щас что не так?

Comment: тонкая полосочка идет до правой стороны страницы, а мне надо ее обрезать, так сказать

Comment: она ведь у вас и щас "обрезана"?

Comment: ну там на скрине видно, сравни скрин, где полоска до правой стороны и на втором скрине, где она обрезана